# Is there any possible to enable this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disable the click event  if li has a class  "active"

HTML :

```
<div class="tabs1">
<ul>
   <li id="menutab1"><a href="#tab1" title="TOS" data-toggle="tab"><span>Terms of Services</span></a></li>
   <li id="menutab2"><a href="#tab2" title="Welcome" data-toggle="tab"><span>Welcome</span></a></li>
   <li id="menutab3"><a href="#tab3" title="Applicant" data-toggle="tab"><span>Applicant</span></a></li>
   <li id="menutab4"><a href="#tab4" title="Personal Data" data-toggle="tab"><span>Personal Data</span></a></li>
   <li id="menutab5"><a href="#tab5" title="Contact Info" data-toggle="tab"><span>Contact Info</span></a></li>
   <li id="menutab6"><a href="#tab6" title="Exam Date" data-toggle="tab"><span>Exam Date</span></a></li>
   <li id="menutab7"><a href="#tab7" title="Submit" data-toggle="tab"><span>Submit</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
   <script type="text/javascript>
         $("menutab").click(false);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use return false:

```
$(selector).on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
      return false;
    }
    // other stuffs 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply some CSS styling for the ".active" class and the in the callback function you can simply skips any tasks that are taking place if the target of the click event has a className that equals to 'active'

Look at his example

```
var prevItem;

var itemClicked = function(event){
    var target = event.target,
        className = target.className;

    if(className === 'active'){
       return;
    }

    if(prevItem) { prevItem.className = ''; }
    target.className = 'active';
    prevItem = target;

   // perform the rest tasks
}

$('#tabs1').on('click', itemClicked);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvrSg/9/

Comment: thanks for the code . how about if li class is active then next button will disable too . 

http://jsfiddle.net/uvrSg/10/

Comment: how about his http://jsfiddle.net/uvrSg/36/

Comment: thanks a lot. more power :)